# Domain Access error on module install - ... 'without WWW. prefix'

Tags: 7, domain-access

I am meticulously trying to follow the directions in the INSTALL.txt file for Domain module. However, after setting up everything as asked in the instructions, I then try to enable the module.  I always get this error:

```
(Currently using Domain Access The domain string is invalid for www.tourismbuilder.com:

WWW prefix handling: Domains must be registered without the www. prefix.

If you are using drush, please provide the --uri option (e.g. drush en domain
        --uri="http://example.com/optional_subdirectory").)
```

The error is not very clear. Domains must be registered where without the www. prefix?

What does this mean? Note, I am not using Drush.

EDIT: VirtualHost settings

```
<VirtualHost 111.68.19.219:80>
    ServerName   tourismbuilder.com
    ServerAlias  *.tourismbuilder.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/tourismbuilder.com/httpdocs
    CustomLog  /var/www/vhosts/tourismbuilder.com/statistics/logs/access_log plesklog
    ErrorLog  /var/www/vhosts/tourismbuilder.com/statistics/logs/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm guessing at some point during the installation you had to type your domain name in (maybe into a string in settings.php). Looks like wherever you've put that you've used `www.tourismbuilder.com` instead of the required `tourismbuilder.com`

Comment: hmm nope. The instructions say to alter the Apache VirtualHost directive; add a line of code at the bottom of settings.php; then then install that very first module, and no others. It's that 3rd step where I am getting the error. Did I screw up the vhost settings? put the settings.php line in the wrong place? Dunno. That msg leaves a lot to be desired, but no, not yet have I been asked to add any domain information.

Comment: Are you configuring the vhost without the www. prefix?

Comment: I am. plz see edit

Comment: I haven't seen whats new in D7 domain access module but from my experience in D6 not including the domain access settings file in end of settings will throw a warning that domain access was not included in bootstrap, since you do not seem to get it that step should be on the clear, www shouldn't be required as far as i know for vhost settings. suggest checking the administrator screen for the domain to check the names of the domains in them and try editing them to get things right